# Windows command script to conditionally Msbuild visual studio projects

Tags: batch-file, command-line, msbuild

I want to write a Windows command script (*.bat) to execute msbuild against two visual studio projects (via *.sln files). The problem is that I need to execute the second Msbuild only when the first build execute successfully. Otherwise, the second Msbuild does not execute.

Below is the partial script I need to run.

```
pushd c:\project1\

msbuild
```

Below is the result of first command

```
...

  0 errors
```

The second command **only executes** when the first runs without error

```
pushd c:\project2\

msbuild project.lab.sln /p:visualstudioversion=10.0
```

The command windows **pauses after runs**

Could anyone show me how to read the result (e.g. 0 errors), and the logic to determine if to run the second line (I am new to command script). **Code example** would be appreciated.

Comment: at first you should check if msbuild is setting an errorlevel.

Comment: You might find the [conditional batch operators](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) `&`, `&&` and `||` useful. But I think it'd be hard to make a simple one-liner if you want appropriate conditional use of `popd`.

Answer (score 1):

As Endoro says, it should set an errorlevel.
Add this as your 2nd command

```
if not errorlevel 1 msbuild command two
```